# Create vector3 with specific heading

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js

So I want to create a 2D flow field in three.js from a working example in p5.js. This is the original source code:

```
var inc = 0.1; //Increment of noise
var yoff = 0;
var scl = var; //Scale of noise field 
var cols = rows = 10; 

for(var y = 0; y < rows; y++)
{
    var xoff = 0;
    for(var x = 0; x < cols; x++)
    {
        var index = x + y * cols;
        var angle = noise(xoff, yoff) * TWO_PI; //Create angle with Perlin noise
        var v = p5.Vector.fromAngle( angle ); //Create new vector from angle
        v.setMag( 0.1 ); //set magnitude of vector
        flowfield[index] = v;
        xoff += inc;
        stroke(0, 50);
        strokeWeight(1);
        push();
        translate(x * scl, y * scl);
        rotate(v.heading());
        line(0, 0, scl, 0);
        pop();
    }
    yoff += inc;
}
```

Now I want to replicate the p5.Vector.fromAngle() function in three.js.

As far as I understand I need to create the vector and then rotate the vector around the z-axis using .applyQuaternion ( quaternion ). However I am rotating the vector around the center and not change it's heading.

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 100, 100, 0 );

var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 ), Math.PI / 2 );

vector.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that I understood you right, apologies if not. A Vector can be thought of as a pointer from the center ("origin") to a specific point in 3D-space. So the only way you can rotate a vector is about the origin. It might help if you add some explanation what you are trying to do, what the expected behaviour is and what you get instead.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use the x/y-plane, the function would basically look like this:

```
function fromAngle(angle) {
  return new THREE.Vector3(
    Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle), 0
  );
}
```

I believe this is a lot simpler than using quaternions for this. If you need more complex three-dimensional rotations, quaternions make a lot of sense. It's also exactly [what p5.js does](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/math/p5.Vector.js#L800).

This function will return a unit-vector (a vector with length 1) pointing in the given direction (so `fromAngle(0) === [1, 0, 0]`, `fromAngle(Math.PI/2) === [0, 1, 0]` and so on).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly.

Comment: Quaternions would have been a bit of an overkill for this :D